# How do I build a data structure in rails so that I can iterate through it like this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling to try and figure out how to build a data structure in ruby.

In my view I wish to iterate through it like this

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
    <%= "#{conversation.meta.subject} - #{conversation.meta.created_at} %>

    <% conversation.messages.each do |message| %>
         <%= message.name %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Messages come from an active record query

```
@messages = Message.find_by_name('john')
```

Meta is a hash like this

```
@meta = { 'subject ' => 'John Messages', 'created_at' => '2012-12-28 10:20:55.230286' }
```

How do I turn this into the @conversations object I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it. Try and post feedback.

```
class Conversation
  attr_reader :name

  class Meta
    attr_accessor :subject, :created_at
    def initialize(attributes = {})
      attributes.each do |key, value|
        send("#{key}=", value)
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    messages # preload
  end

  def messages
    @messages ||= Message.where(:name => name).order("created_at") # .find_by_name returns a single object, but you waiting for an Array, so use .where
  end

  def default_meta_attributes
    {:subject => "#{name} Messages", :created_at => messages.last.created_at}
  end

  def meta(attrs={})
    @meta ||= Meta.new(attrs.blank? ? default_meta_attributes : attrs)
  end

end

# test

@conversations = []
@conversations << Conversation.new("John")

@conversations.each do |conversation|
  puts conversation.meta.subject
  puts conversation.meta.created_at
  puts "Now conversation messages of #{conversation.name}"
  conversation.messages.each do |message|
    puts message.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. Creating a class within a class is new to me. Works perfectly and I can modify from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Conversation
 - subject : string

has_many :messages

Message
 - name : string

belongs_to :conversation
```

Change this line:

```
<%= "#{conversation.meta.subject} - #{conversation.meta.created_at} %>
```

to

```
<%= "#{conversation.subject} - #{conversation.created_at} %>
```

@conversations would probably come from a user's conversation, so make Conversation belong_to :user

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I was looking for a way to build an object using maybe a module or class. Conversation doesnt exist in the database so it cant be related to anything.

Comment: I'm suggesting you make it a model, and put it in the database

Comment: It's OK not to use the database for this but how do you plan to discern which messages belong to which conversation?

Comment: That bit is fine and I abstracted it because it doesnt matter. I just need to know how to build the conversation object.